# How to get g++ to ignore warnings from included projects

Tags: makefile, g++

I'm making a new project that is dependent on two other projects (written by others). While I'm developing my code I would like to use g++ options such as `-Wall -pedantic -Werror` but when I use these options I get a flood of warnings by including files from the other two projects.

Is there any way I can ignore the warnings from those two projects but still see the warnings from my own project?

Comment: Are you `#include` files from the other projects? If so, you could wrap those includes with `#pragma`s that [alter the warning settings](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html#Diagnostic-Pragmas).

Comment: @Christian.K This sounds promising. Let me check into it. Thank you.

Comment: @Christian.K It doesn't seem to be the cleanest fix (I had to ignore on a warning by warning basis), but it definitely worked.

Comment: Are you using an IDE, or compiling their source directly?

Comment: @TylerJandreau I'm compiling their source directly.

Answer (score 0):

If you're compiling their source directly via a makefile, you can make optional `CPPFLAGS`which you can use for conditional compilation parameters. For example:

`CPPFLAGS=-Wall -pedantic -Werror` for your project and `CPPFLAGS=-g` for their project files (or something).

Take the following sample makefile. Assume you wrote `factorial.cpp` and `hello.cpp` and they wrote `main.cpp`:

```
CPPFLAGS+=-Wall -pedantic -Werror

all: hello

hello: main.o factorial.o hello.o
    g++ main.o factorial.o hello.o -o hello

main.o: main.cpp
    g++ -c main.cpp

factorial.o: factorial.cpp
    g++ -c $(CPPFLAGS) factorial.cpp

hello.o: hello.cpp
    g++ -c $(CPPFLAGS) hello.cpp

clean:
    rm -rf *o hello
```

Try something like that and get back to me.